# How to open Command Line application built from Xcode outside of Xcode?

Tags: c++, xcode, macos

I have a console application project which uses my own framework. When I build and run the application from Xcode it's executed successfully. However when I try to open the executable from terminal outside of Xcode I get the following error:

```
dyld: Library not loaded: @rpath/Logic.framework/Versions/A/Logic
  Referenced from: /Users/semyon/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/VocalTrainer-fyzwymbxfxusrqejhssrjfeovnqg/Build/Products/Debug/./MvxGenerator
  Reason: image not found
zsh: abort      ./MvxGenerator
```

The question is: How to deliver the release build of my command line application which uses a framework?

Answer (score 0):

You need to install the framework/ dynamic library at `@executable_path/../Resources/lib` folder. If you share a .app bundle, just copy it in `Contents/MacOS/Resources/lib` folder. If a binary, make sure your installer keeps the framework at the right place.

You may want to inspect other open source app bundles which do this:

- Cmake
- Visual Studio Code

etc

Comment: It works with .app bundle, but not with command line app